# Can I print out somehow result of rand() function called from Cypher?

Tags: cypher, memgraphdb, opencypher

I have the following code:

```
MATCH (:City {name: 'London'})-[road:Road]->(city:City)
WHERE NOT  city.name IN ['Islington', 'Wembley']
RETURN city.name
ORDER BY road.length ASC
LIMIT 1 + toInteger(7*rand());
```

On each run I get differnt number of results as I should. I understant that the number of reulsts depend on result of `1 + toInteger(7*rand());`. But what I would like to know can I see the result of `rand()`, which number is genrated? My pseudo code would be somethign like:

```
LUCKYNUMBER=toInteger(7*rand())
PRINT LUCKYNUMBER
LIMIT 1 + LUCKYNUMBER
```

I presume that `RETURN` is the same as `PRINT`, but how do I create a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cypher, you can create a variable by prefixing the name of the variable with a dollar sign `($)`. So, you can create the variable `LUCKYNUMBER` as follows:

```
WITH toInteger(7*rand()) AS LUCKYNUMBER
```

You can also use the `RETURN` statement to return the value of a variable along with the query results, like this:

```
WITH toInteger(7*rand()) AS LUCKYNUMBER
RETURN LUCKYNUMBER
```

You can also use the `PRINT` statement to output the value of a variable to the console, like this:

```
WITH toInteger(7*rand()) AS LUCKYNUMBER
PRINT LUCKYNUMBER
```

In your query, you should use `WITH` statement in order to create a variable, like this:

```
MATCH (:City {name: 'London'})-[road:Road]->(city:City)
WHERE NOT  city.name IN ['Islington', 'Wembley']
WITH toInteger(7*rand()) AS LUCKYNUMBER
RETURN city.name
ORDER BY road.length ASC
LIMIT 1 + LUCKYNUMBER;
```

It will create a variable `LUCKYNUMBER`, store the result of `toInteger(7*rand())` in it, and then you can use this variable in your query as you would use any other variable.

This query will return a random number of city names in the range of 1 to 8, and you will see the value of the `LUCKYNUMBER` variable returned along with the city names.

Comment: This PRINT statement that you mentioned is also part of Cypher?